# Java field injection via annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, code-injection

I'm trying to write the code to annotate a field in a class so that the value of that field is set from a config file.  This is virtually identical to the @Value attribute that the spring framework has, but for reasons I won't go into, I'm not using the spring framework.

The project I'm working on is a web app using the Jersey framework.  I apologize for all the up-front information, but for the sake of completeness, here's a basic setup of what I have:

This is the main application class:

```
package com.ttrr.myservice;

import com.ttrr.myservice.controllers.MyController;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // register root resources            
        classes.add(MyController.class);

        return classes;
    }
}
```

This is the MyController class, that I want annotations to work in:

```
package com.ttrr.myservice.controllers;

import com.ttrr.myservice.annotations.Property;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;

@Path("test")
public class MyController {

    @Property("my.value.from.config")
    private String myValue;

    @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    @Path("/testPage")
    public String testPage(@Context ServletContext context) {        

        return "<p>" + myValue + "</p>";
    }
}
```

My annotations interface is pretty straight forward:

```
package com.ttrr.myservice.annotations;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Property {
    String value() default "";
}
```

And I have an annotation parser class:

```
package com.ttrr.myservice.annotations;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertyParser {

    public static Properties properties;

    static {
        properties = new Properties();
        try {
            Property.class.getClassLoader();

            Properties defaults = new Properties();
            defaults.load(Property.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));

            for(Object key : defaults.keySet()) {
                properties.put(key, defaults.get(key));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            //in this case do nothing, properties will simply be empty
        }
    }

    public void parse(Class<?> clazz) throws Exception {

        Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();

        for (Field field : fields) {
            if (field.isAnnotationPresent(Property.class)) {
                Property property = field.getAnnotation(Property.class);
                String value = property.value();

                if (!"".equals(value)) {
                    field.set(clazz, properties.getProperty(value));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where I'm really struggling is putting it all together, and getting the value from my application.properties file into an instance of the MyController class.

Thanks for taking the time to read all that!  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where are you calling your parse(...) method?

Comment: Initially, I was calling parse() in the MyApplication.getClasses() method, however it could not set the value appropriately, because at that point all it had was the Class<?> and not an instance to set the value into (at least, I think that was the problem).  The line in parse() that reads: field.set(clazz, properties.getProperty(value)); is the problem.

Comment: @wbj The way you are calling [Field#set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#set%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) you will be setting the value successfully only if the field is `static` in that case the `obj` argument `clazz` is obsolete and may be `null` otherwise (if the field is not static) you'll end up with a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` unless you pass an instance as `obj`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you're trying to set the values is incorrect because you need an instance to set the value.

```
field.set(clazz, properties.getProperty(value));
```

should be:

```
field.set(instance, properties.getProperty(value));
```

And you should add an argument to your parse method:

```
public void parse(Class<?> clazz, Object instance) throws Exception {
```

Comment: Ok, thanks...this was definitely part of the problem.  I've got it working now.  I got rid of the Class<?> clazz parameter altogether, and just pass in the instance.  The drawback is that I had to add a constructor to the MyController class that called the parse() method.  I'm going to mark this as the answer, but I'd rather not have to add a constructer with an explicit call to parse() for every class I write.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Also, I'd vote your answer up, but I don't have sufficient reputation :(

Comment: Indeed the clazz parameter is no longer necessary if you pass an instance to the method! I'm glad I could help!